# Ppass a variable in pipeline to html.groovy template

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use a variable that I defined in Jenkins pipeline in html.groovy template by using email-ext.

I send an email by following code.

```
    post {
    always {
        emailext (
            to: 'myemail@email.co.kr',
            subject: "[BuildResult][${currentBuild.currentResult}] - Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER})",
            presendScript: '',
            body: '''${SCRIPT, template="aaa.email.groovy.template"}''',
            attachLog: true
        )
    }
```

Inside the template I use build parameters by using "build.envorinment"

but cannot find a way to use variables I defined in environment in pipeline like following.

```
pipeline {
envorinemnt {
    DLLS = 'test'
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling for environment is incorrect, you are using "envorinemnt" both in the pipeline as well as template. "environment" try this out first.

Assuming that spelling mistake is not the case.

Then in your body of the template you can use something like this to call the defined variable.

```
    <%
def buildnumber = build.getEnvVars()["BUILD_NUMBER"];
    
%>


<tr>
      <td>BuildNumber:</td>
      <td>${buildnumber}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```